# What requirement does a function need to be the magnitude of a gradient?

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have an domain(open and path connected) $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and a smooth function $g$ defined on U. Could we find a function $f$ on $U$ so that $g=\|\nabla f\|$? (One can think $U$ simply as a disk or an annulus). If not possible, what sufficient conditions do we need for $g$?

I was trying to find a unit vector field $\hat{n}$ so that $\nabla\times(g\hat{n})=0$ but no significant results have been found.

Besides, I was also thinking about if there is steady solution to the PDE $\partial_t f(x,y,t)+sgn(f-c)(\|\nabla f\|-g)=0$ for some suitably chosen $c$.